# why can't push the lasted created app to heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am practicing django2 on Python3, and want to deploy the project on heroku. when I run the fellow command:

```
 $ git init
 $ git add .
 $ git commit -am "Ready for deployment to heroku"
 $ git staus
```

everything is fine ,then:

```
$ heroku create
```

and the last command I get some problem:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

[app pacific-plateau-99737. was deleted already, how to push the new created app  hidden-escarpment-89466?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHnfA.png)

Comment: Please post your error message as code-formatted text, not as an image.

Comment: thank you. I solved this , just need to delete .git file